# Where to ask website questions?

Tags: discussion

For some reason I was under the impression this site was for websites too, but FAQ explicitly says it's not for that.

Where can I ask questions about web services? Why do all the website tags (like youtube) exist?

Answer (score 2):

We have a site for [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com). If there's tools that tap into a web services and run on a desktop, they might have a tag related to the service for the tool.